# Nested select statement in regexp_like does not resolve correctly

Tags: sql, loops, select, nested, amazon-athena

I'm very new to AWS & Athena. I'm using Athena to query a data file (CSV) from S3 using glue crawlers to create catalog and then querying that info. I have the catalog table created by glue, containing fName, sName, mName info. I'm trying to search a regexp pattern from all the rows and columns with a single query.

I have created a second table containing the column names of the primary table, i.e. fName, sName, mName.

I would like to loop through the second table rows -> using each value in my regexp_like function to search for any names starting with 'B'
e.g.

```
where regexp_like(fname,'^B') 
where regexp_like(sname,'^B')
where regexp_like(mname,'^B')
```

and display all of them.

Is this possible? I have not been able to get the first query working even when hardcoding the search criteria
e.g.

```
select * from primary_table
where regexp_like((Select column from secondary_table where column_name='fname'),'^B')
```

above SQL -> Select column from secondary_table where column_name='fname' resolves to fname as string, not fname column in primary table.

Comment: Adding sample data to your question would make it easier for others to understand.

Comment: Hi Tim sorry about that, please imaging it as a table with 3 columns fname, sname, mname. and three columns have names for ppl. their first,last,and middle names. I need to search through this table for anyone that has any part of their name starting with B. i.e. if first or last or middles or all names start with B it should be displayed. To help with this I created a second table that keeps the column names on the first table. I wanted to try to loop through this second table picking a new column name and doing the regexp_like search against it for 'B'. hope this helps

Comment: That lengthy comment doesn't really answer my question though `:-(`

Answer (score 0):

Storing column names and table names *as data* is generally not recommended.  In order to use the information, you need to use dynamic SQL -- that is, construct the query as a string and execute that.

You can get something similar using a lot of logic.  But you have to check for each column explicitly:

```
select p.*
from primary p join
     secondary s
     on s.column_name = 'fname' and regexp_like(p.fname, '^B') or
        s.column_name = 'sname' and regexp_like(p.sname, '^B') or
        s.column_name = 'mname' and regexp_like(p.mname, '^B') ;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon for the help. I'm guessing that Athena/presto is not able to do the dynamic SQL that I was hoping for...? that being said is there anyway to make the solution you sent a bit more dynamic? Ideally I would not know how many columns or column names are going to be present in the table and am looking for a method to run through them all and search? Thanks

Comment: @TR_Dev . . . You can do the dynamic SQL in Python or whatever programming tool you like.